# Regex (java) extract one value from multiple values url

Tags: java, regex, url, extract

How can I get ID=2053 from below string, I want get value from field no 5 from this URL:

```
f('1132', 'TEXT', '273', '', '2053', 'TEXT', '1081', '0', '0', '', 'TEXT', '',0);
```

I was trying to get this value by doing like this:

```
String REGEXP = "'(.\\d*)'/g";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXP);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);
if (matcher.find()) {
    docID.setId(matcher.group(2));
}
```

but I get `ID=null`. Probably because matcher matches only first field. How can I create regex to get value found on the fifth position

Comment: what is f?array?or...

Comment: this is javascript url it looks like: javascript: f_123('1132', 'text1', '273', '', '2053', 'text2', '1081', '0', '0', '', 'text3', '',0);

Comment: That doesn't look anything like a URL, but I went with it.

Comment: why don't you split the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Split approach

You don't need a regex to get that value, if you `split` the string by `,` then you can get the value.

```
String str = "f('1132', 'TEXT', '273', '', '2053', 'TEXT', '1081', '0', '0', '', 'TEXT', '',0);";
String[] arr = str.split(",");

System.out.println("Value is: " + arr[4]);
// Prints:
// Value is: '2053'
```

**[IDE One Example](https://ideone.com/esXs2O)**

### Regex approach

However, if you still want to use a regex, then you could use a regex like this:

```
^(?:[^,]*,){4} '(\d+)'
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA1xE7/1)**

```
// REGEX APPROACH
String str = "f('1132', 'TEXT', '273', '', '2053', 'TEXT', '1081', '0', '0', '', 'TEXT', '',0);";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(?:[^,]*,){4} '(\\d+)'").matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to substring on the split approach.

Comment: thank you very much this is what I wanted to achieve. best regards

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be `'([^']*)'`, and then access `group(1)`.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'").matcher(URL);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    m.find(); // skip first 4 matches
}
if (m.find()) {
    docID.setId(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for example, but exactly the same loop've done this example and it works, but if there is a simpler possibility of not using a loop to create regex getting  fifth value?